# Combobox text when clearing items

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm dealing with the fact that when I clear items in a combobox programmatically, the text do not change and keep the last selected item.

How can I do it?

Comment: Share the Code which you have tried.

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Try `comboBox.Text = string.Empty;`

Comment: How do you clear the items?

Comment: comboBox.Text = "";  ?

Comment: what type of application is this? winforms?wpf?web?

Comment: @un-lucky  I clear items  cb.Items.Clear(); but, is there any way, the text get the default Text once items are cleared?   WinForms

Comment: There is no "default" text for a combobox. The default is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
comboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Or

```
comboBox.Items.Clear();
comboBox.ResetText();
```

Comment: The question is about WinForms look @ the comment of Apalabrados ths owner of question

Answer (score 0):

Another way for combo boxes:

Populate

```
comboBox1.DataSource = new string[] { "", "bruce", "clark", "tony" };
```

Clear

```
comboBox1.DataSource = null;
```